# How can I create an Internet Explorer addon?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, ieaddon

How to create an Internet Explorer addon with .net. All I need is a just a menu under right click context menu.

.net is a must.

Edit: What I am trying to do is add a context menu to IE.

Comment: Perhaps [Add-in Express](http://www.add-in-express.com/programming-internet-explorer/developing-addons.php) is a solution for you. If ".NET is a must", I get the feeling that you'd run screaming from COM programming.

Comment: It costs a lot comparing what I try to achieve. Considering that, this leaves me alone together with COM programming :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good example explaining how to create a context menu with C#

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/menus/IE_Context_Menu_Installer.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can have a look at those two:

- [Creating an Internet Explorer Add-in Toolbar Button using C++ and ATL](http://10rem.net/blog/2011/02/22/creating-an-internet-explorer-add-in-toolbar-button-using-cplusplus-and-atl)
- [Creating Add-ons for Internet Explorer: Customizing Menus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735853%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This site looks promising:

http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/dev.asp

It also mentions that you may be able to use registry entries to add a context menu:

> #### Creating a context menu item that launches a program with the selected text
>
> At the command prompt, run:

```
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\MENUITEMNAME" /ve /d "file://C:\Program Files\EXTENDIE\MENUITEMSCRIPT.htm"
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MenuExt\MENUITEMNAME" /v "Contexts" /t REG_DWORD /d 16
```

Save the following as `C:\Program Files\ExtendIE\MenuItemScript.htm`

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var parentwin = external.menuArguments; var doc = parentwin.document;
var sel = doc.selection; var rng = sel.createRange(); var str = new String(rng.text);
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
// Replace with your executable name
oShell.ShellExecute("cmd", "/k @echo " + str);
oShell = null;
</SCRIPT>
```